# Como acessar um banco MySql do OpenShift via Jdbc pelo Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: mysql, openshift

Quero acessar um banco MySql hospedado no OpenShift via Jdbc a partir do Google Spreadsheet. É possível?

No Google Spreadsheet, em `Ferramentas -> Editor de Scripts`, estou tendo problemas com a string de conexão que tá nesse formato:

```
var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://HOST:PORTA/DB_NAME", "USERPHPMYADMIN", "SENHAPHPMYADMIN");
```

Comment: Qual o problema ? sendo que o mysql tem acesso externo ?

Comment: mysql://URLDOOPENSHIFT:3306, qual esta sendo o problema ?

Comment: David, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Há alguma mensagem de erro? VOcê consegue se conectar de outro local? Tente fazer um programinha simples em Java, uma classe Main para fazer a conexão e testar para ver se consegue. Como o @Otto já comentou, você precisa habilitar o acesso externo, pois no MySQL por padrão ele não permite conexão remota. Então primeiramente verifique se o usuário usado no `getConnection` tem as devidas permissões. Abraço!

Comment: Ok, vou testar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Bem, verifiquei que o usuário que estou utilizando para acessar o mysql no openshift é o root e, portanto, deveria ter acesso a tudo. Vou refazer a pergunta: É possivel acessar remotamente um banco de dados MySql hospedado no OpenShift?